# How can i change queryset on SelectField?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a form, and a select input, i need change the queryset of tthat select, how can i make this?

my form exemple:

```
class myModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = myModel
    fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try overriding `__init__` and setting the queryset on your field:

```
class myModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['<your_field_name'].queryset = <your_queryset>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make a form to catch only some of the field of the model you have to specify such field:

```
class Meta:
    model = myModel
    fields = ['field1','field3','field12']
```

if you mean that you want to make a change into the form after you get it into your view:

```
form = myModelForm(request.POST)
form.cleaned_data['field1'] = 'change what you want'
```

Comment: but that's not  whats i need, i need to chage the query set in a selectField, not chage my field